# Jekyll automatically processing rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I want to filter out from `site.pages` all pages with a given YAML frontmatter type `'project'`.

To do this I've done this:

```
{% sorted_for page in site.pages sort_by:title %}                       
{% if page.type == 'project' %}
do something
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This uses the [sorted_for](https://gist.github.com/mbland/3812259) plugin. What I want to do now, however is to arrange these in css rows of four.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">{{ page1.title }}</div>
<div class="span3">{{ page2.title }}</div>
<div class="span3">{{ page3.title }}</div>
<div class="span3">{{ pagen.title }}</div>
</div>
...
```

And so forth, until the rows run out. How can I access the information I need to do this? Unfortunately the for loop iterator number will be wrong, as it will also tick through the non-project pages. Is there a clean way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:

I couldn't get the `sorted_for` plugin to work in my machine, so I tested my solution with a regular `for` instead.*

### Step 1

As you can't use [`forloop.index`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/for-loops#index) because you're filtering out some pages, you need to count the loops by yourself, by writing to a variable with [`assign`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/logic#assign).

The following code will just list your pages with a correct loop iterator *(by counting just the pages that are actually listed)*:

```
{% assign loopindex = 0 %}
{% for page in site.pages %}                       
  {% if page.type == 'project' %}
    {% assign loopindex = loopindex | plus: 1 %}
    <div class="span3">{{ loopindex }} {{ page.title }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

### Step 2

You need to display `<div class="row">` with every first row and `</div>` with every fourth row.

To find the first and fourth rows, you can use `modulo`:

```
{% assign loopindex = 0 %}
{% for page in site.pages %}                       
  {% if page.type == 'project' %}
    {% assign loopindex = loopindex | plus: 1 %}
    {% assign rowfinder = loopindex | modulo: 4 %}
    <div class="span3">{{ loopindex }} {{ rowfinder }} {{ page.title }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`rowfinder` will always repeat the sequence **1, 2, 3, 0**.

### Step 3:

So you display `<div class="row">` when `rowfinder` is `1`, and `</div>` when `rowfinder` is `0`:

```
{% assign loopindex = 0 %}
{% for page in site.pages %}                       
  {% if page.type == 'project' %}
    {% assign loopindex = loopindex | plus: 1 %}
    {% assign rowfinder = loopindex | modulo: 4 %}
    {% if rowfinder == 1 %}
      <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">{{ page.title }}</div>
    {% elsif rowfinder == 0 %}
      <div class="span3">{{ page.title }}</div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="span3">{{ page.title }}</div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

### Step 4:

Now there's only one small thing left: when the number of pages is not a multiple of 4, there's a `</div>` missing at the end.

When the number of pages **is** a multiple of 4, the last value of `rowfinder` will be `0`.
So we just need to display the `</div>` when the value of `rowfinder` is anything else but `0`.
So just put this after the for loop:

```
{% if rowfinder != 0 %}
      </div>
{% endif %}
```

...and that's it!